# Sum all columns in MySQL with same initially name or letters

Tags: php, mysql

I have columns red1, green1, red2, green2, red3, green3 .... red1623, green1623 and I wish SUM only red% columns in PHP but without large code like:

`SELECT SUM(red1) + SUM(red2) + .... + SUM(red1623)`

Anyone can help!

I find this but I dont understand this code. I need code in PHP.

```
SET @colname = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`column_name`) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='dnevnik' AND `column_name` LIKE 'redovno%');
SET @table = '1';
SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT SUM(',@colname,') FROM ', @table);
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: Normalize your data, and the task will become trivial.

Comment: What’s the problem with the large sql, if it does the job? You can generate it with the help of a `for`on the PHP side.

Comment: I agree with @Akina here, the issue is the database design. Multiple similar columns in a single table is very rarely the correct solution, whether it's two similar columns or, in your case, apparently 1623 similar columns. Data such as these should be in a separate linked table.

Comment: The idea of the first part of the query you quoted is to return the list of column names in the table. So you could run that query first, get the results into a PHP array, and then use a simple loop to build up your query with all the hundreds of different column names that you want to sum. That would do the job, and would deal with the situation where you might add new columns `red1624` and `green1624`, but it's really only taping over the issues with the database layout. If it's not too late, I'd urge you to redesign. " Database normalisation" is the search term.

Answer (score 1):

This works! Maybe not the best solution but work.
For all who won't normalize data :D and have same problem like me:

```
<?php
include_once 'assets/conn.php';

for ($id = 1; $id <= 3000; $id++) {

$sql = "SELECT SUM(red$id) AS RED FROM mytable;";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$sum += $row['RED'];
}
}

echo $sum;

?>
```

Comment: It also requires up to 3000 queries. Just use php to write one query with 3000 columns.